# json.loads return string instead of int ? python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this json string :`{"bussID":"5625"}`

```
json1=json.loads('{"bussID":"5625"}')
value=json1['bussID']
if not isinstance(value, (int, long)):
    print("string")
```

I don't understand why the value is not integer? it's string !

Comment: This doesnt work, your json.loads parameter is not json

Answer (score 0):

Check your **json** lib, it should work  fine:

```
import json

json1 = json.loads('{"bussID":5625}')
value = json1['bussID']

print value, isinstance(value, int)
```

> 5625 True

Comment: thank you for your response, what should I check with json.lib ?

Comment: same behaviour as @Rustem observed as well as using Python 3.3; isinstance(value, int) = True

Comment: @jermenkoo but the the number 5625 should written as "5625"

Comment: How can you expect to get an int, if you value you have in your json (`"5625"`) is a string

Comment: @TimCastelijns that's the reason why I am asking ?

Comment: @david if you have "5625" it is string, if you have 5625 - it is int. Should everywhere everytime